# How do I fix problems importing Android projects from Eclipse 3.5 to Eclipse 4.2?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I recently formatted my old Ubuntu 10.04 and upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, since Netbeans 3.5 were too old to manage some Android projects which I'm working on. 
I installed Eclipse 4.2 following [this guide](http://blog.brunobraga.net/eclipse-42-in-ubuntu-1204), than I installed the last version of android Development Toolkit (ADT r21) and updated android packages. 
Since I had the same error on all Android projects ("The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files [...] Java Problem") I searched for a solution and found [this in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073222/java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse). 
Than having other troubles importing one of my projects I read other issues, and read [this solution in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493038/move-android-eclipse-project-into-workspace/6459478#6459478).
Now the project is imported, but I obain 645 errors, always related to classes not resolved (eg. BluetootAdapter, Calendar, ContentProviderOperation), classes not allowed (eg. String), etc. I never had this issues in Ubuntu 10.04 with Eclipse 3.5. I 
Maybe oracle-java7 has lead to this? Or did I have some configuration error related to java o to the ADT?

Hope to solve without re-installing java, elcipse and ADT. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your project>Build path>configure build path>chose android from the list appears to your left>then check android 4.x.x (your preference)>press OK

Comment: Thanks Husam, now I reduced error down to 32 choosing API level 4.0.3 (the previous selected was 1.6). However, my projecte have to work from the 2.2 version. I'll check tomorrow if this is possible, now I'm asleep.
Thanks again!

Comment: I finished to fix my errors, your solution was the right one, thanks again!

Comment: you are more than welcome Oscar