# Confused about Eclipse workspaces

Tags: android, eclipse, project, workspace

I wanted to create a copy of my Android project in Eclipse so I can modify the copy without touching the original. So I proceeded to create a new workspace. I thought I was working in the new workspace because the path of the workspace is show at the top of the menu bar in Eclipse but I saw:

1) there are no project files in my new workspace directory so I copied a folder with all the project files in it, including a file I changed this morning with today's date

2) when I went to add a new .jar file via this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285306/setting-up-google-api-java-client-developing-environment/7370807#7370807), I saw the old jar file workspace was listed rather than my new workspace directory path when doing the 5th step of the advice.

So here are my questions:
1) do I need a new workspace to avoid overwriting my old project code?
2) do I need to import the project that I touched this morning so that Eclipse recognizes its new location?
3) was it still using the old jar file in the old workspace? did I interpret that correctly?

Should I follow these steps to clean things up as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493038/move-android-eclipse-project-into-workspace/5576835#5576835):

> Make a new android project choosing "Create project from existing source", making sure that the source directory is indeed outside your workspace (you'll have to live with this for a second). This should a) make the necessary .project/.classpath files in the source directory (which is still outside your workspace for now) and b) make the project show up in your list in Eclipse.
>
> Right click the project in the Package Explorer and choose Delete, making sure that the option to delete files on disk is unchecked when it comes up.
>
> Now import the project like you would any other project (you can do this now because the .project/.classpath files were created in step 1 above). There should be an option when importing for "Copy projects into workspace", so tick that option.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above just duplicate the project. To do so:
- in your new workspace:

```
go to File --> New --> Project... --> Android Project from Existing Code -->
```

Browse for your original project, make sure you check '**copy project into workspace**' box and click finish.

Comment: Thanks, I think the instructions I was following said to not check that box which may be why my workspace folder was empty. I'll try again with your suggestion.

Comment: This worked like a champ. It was important, I think, to include the note about checking the copy project into workspace so I voted for this one but the others were also correct so I'm upvoting those as well. Thanks everyone for the super-quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

Workspaces are just ProjectSets and configuration sets, so you can have a completely different GUI design depending on what you are doing. I have a Workspace for all of my company projects, as well as i have a workspace for all of my client projects. The workspaces keep the separate and can hav different configurations.

For what you are looking to do, the best thing would be to just in Explorer, create a copy of the entire Project folder, and rename it something else (Project1)-(Project2).

Then back in eclipse, File -> Import -> Existing Project

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll check this out right now and accept which one works. Thanks for the explanation. BTW, I'm on a Mac so I assume that would be Finder in which I make the change.

Comment: Sounds good! As the other answer states, you can make a new workspace for the project, however if you move windows around in the IDE, the change will not carry over from Workspace to Workspace, by importing them both into the same workspace with different names, you can change your configs and have it be the same for each project.

Comment: Followup question, if I may. What was the Copy Working Sets option when I was Importing the project? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Workspaces in Eclipse might or might not contain the code. Usually, the actual project get imported into the workspace. So, you can have multiple workspaces that all point to the same code. You can right click on the files and look at the resource tab to see where the files are actually located.

Best approach is to duplicate the code itself, and create a separate workspace for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out right now and accept which one works. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: By the way, I recommend not placing code in the actual workspace. It's too easy to delete a workspace and it mixes the IDE with the project, which should be avoided.